# What is the story behind the new message at app launch?

Tags: ingress

Ingress had ADA's nice female voice since its early days as the welcoming message but it has changed over the past few days into something like a quarrel between ADA and a male voice. It goes like this:

> ADA : I'm being watched
>   The male voice : The tool is in your hands. The scanner is the key.

Does anyone know the story behind it?

Comment: @aytimothy I didn't know that the voice belonged to Roland Jarvis at the time of asking, so it should remain as "the male voice".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out to belong to Roland Jarvis and it's an excerpt from his [Redemption Speech](http://goo.gl/qYnaI7).

[Here is the post](https://plus.google.com/114524860160125702831/posts/HrEUQZdaFPT) and its content linking it back to the Redemption Speech.

> *The tool is in your hands, the scanner is the key.*
>   It's FlashbackFriday - some of you might not be familiar with the voice you recently heard in the scanner. That is an excerpt from the
>   Redemption Speech by the Enlightened's [+Roland Jarvis](https://plus.google.com/103568659333550762891).
>
> It was released in August 2013 via 36 Media items that investigators,
>   many from Operation Essex, helped to compile and decrypt. It was an
>   exciting time and an impressive display of cooperation from agents
>   from both factions. This experience brought new investigators into
>   fold.
>
> LISTEN: [+Fev Games](https://plus.google.com/107775863960764314917) video –
>
> READ: Jarvis Redemption Speech text – http://goo.gl/qYnaI7

Comment: is this official? First I've upvoted you, but as I see, it is a fevgame or decodeingress thing. Do we write the story?

Answer (score 5):

This is about the story behind the game, and also depends on how the anomalies do result. I was in Milano, after then in Wien and then Rotterdam. The Obsidian and the Aegis Nova was won by the Enlightened faction.

Last two anomalies were won by the Enlightened in a raw, which means the we've captured ADA. This is why you cannot hack ADA refactor virus anymore. MUFG capsules also do not multiply ADA.

With the Via Lux Anomaly, the score is 7 to 7 at the moment. I am so curious what is going to happen... I'm living in Budapest, and on September 24th it will be a satellite city for the anomaly also.